# No permission to access centos samba server from Windows 10

Tags: centos, samba

I am trying to setup a Samba file sharing server in Centos 8

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-samba-centos-8/

The first half, creating an annonymous share (not secured) worked, as expected. There were some problems in the beginning but using hints [from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/625693/samba-server-on-centos-sees-shared-directories-but-no-files-visible) it was ultimately fixed.

I then tried making a secure server and ran into problems. The few things I did different from the linked tutorial when making a secure server are:

1) At the point where it adds a secure group

```
$ sudo groupadd secure_group
```

I used a group name of secure_group_smb. I use this same group name in the smb.conf file later

2) At the point where the tutorial adds a user for samba server

```
sudo useradd -g secure_group linuxuser
```

I used username (my existing CentOS administrator user) instead of linuxuser (a new user, which is what I think the tutorial is suggesting to do)

I did everything else as instructed there, but when I tried to connect to the CentOS machine from Windows, I got the "Do not have permission to access" error message.

[image]

After googling around for a while I tried a bunch of stuff and I still got the same error. So I deleted all the shared folders I created in /srv/samba, I deleted secure_group_smb using sudo groupdel secure_group_smb, and started over following the instructions in the tutorial linked earlier. However, now I cannot even get the first part to work, that is, getting an anonymous share. I am still getting the same "Do not have permission to access" error in Windows when I try to connect it to the linux machine.

What is going on here? How can I find out what exactly is it that is blocking me from connecting to the linux computer? Is there a way to completely wipe everything I did related to samba and start over fresh in CentOS?

Comment: Did you add the user to the group `secure_group` or `secure_group_smb`?

Comment: @Panki I added to secure_group_smb

Comment: @Panki in either case I would like to know how to know how to do a clean start

Comment: @Panki Any ideas about this? - [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)

Comment: @user13267 Any ideas? - [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592705/how-to-change-permissions-and-access-on-a-samba-network-share-hosted-on-centos7)